# Check if I'm supervised

Tags: networking, security, wireshark, sniffing

Is there any software that I can use to check If my computer is supervised? I want to know if anyone is sniffing my traffic out of my computer with wireshark or another software.

Is this possible?

Comment: No way anyone can tell. What environment are you talking about? Corporate? Personal network? Public networks? Which networking connection? Which devices? Which operating systems? But let's say, no, there is no magic software that could tell you you're supervised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is running locally, you could try to see the process (process explorer on Windows or ps on Linux). You could also derive it from disk (and cpu) activity patterns. Finally, you could analyse the traffic yourself to see if there is a data stream sending your behaviour to a remote machine. See some suggestions [here](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-detect-computer-email-monitoring-or-spying-software/).

If it is running on your network path, there is now way to check it using software.

I suggest you follow the legal route: send in a formal request to disclose if you are being monitored. Prepare for a [Glomar response](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glomar_response) though.

The safest for you would be to behave as-if you actually are being watched. In the meanwhile, you could check out [this website.](http://www.amibeingwatched.com/)